# Reducing a List of Case Classes to a Count of the Case Classes

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I currently have a group RDD of the form `((id, code), (list of events with keys id and code))`. Looking below, the ID is `000406106-01`, the code is `496`, and the individual events are each `Diagnostic` case class. What I was hoping to do was obtain an RDD of the form `((id, code), count of events)`. Essentially, I wanted to collapse the `CompactBuffer` object of `Diagnostic` events into a count of of the events. Any suggestions?

```
    ID         CODE               EVENT1                                                     EVENT2
((000406106-01,496),CompactBuffer(Diagnostic(000406106-01,Sun Apr 16 02:24:00 UTC 2006,496), Diagnostic(000406106-01,Fri Jul 20 15:30:00 UTC 2012,496), Diagnostic(000406106-01,Tue Dec 23 17:00:00 UTC 2014,496), Diagnostic(000406106-01,Wed Jan 06 20:45:00 UTC 2010,496), Diagnostic(000406106-01,Fri Mar 04 16:30:00 UTC 2011,496), Diagnostic(000406106-01,Sun Aug 04 04:51:00 UTC 2013,496), Diagnostic(000406106-01,Fri Mar 11 16:00:00 UTC 2011,496), Diagnostic(000406106-01,Tue Jul 10 13:45:00 UTC 2012,496), Diagnostic(000406106-01,Wed Jun 15 20:00:00 UTC 2005,496), Diagnostic(000406106-01,Tue Dec 29 13:30:00 UTC 2009,496), Diagnostic(000406106-01,Fri Jul 13 13:30:00 UTC 2012,496), Diagnostic(000406106-01,Thu Jul 26 03:40:00 UTC 2007,496), Diagnostic(000406106-01,Mon Jun 13 14:45:00 UTC 2005,496), Diagnostic(000406106-01,Wed Dec 24 18:00:00 UTC 2014,496), Diagnostic(000406106-01,Thu Mar 03 15:45:00 UTC 2011,496), Diagnostic(000406106-01,Wed Dec 31 15:00:00 UTC 2014,496), Diagnostic(000406106-01,Sat Jul 26 04:39:00 UTC 2008,496), Diagnostic(000406106-01,Thu Dec 31 20:30:00 UTC 2009,496)))
```

What I'm looking for:

```
     ID        CODE COUNT
((000406106-01,496), 20)
```

Edit: For clarity's sake, here's how the RDD above is being generated:

```
val grpDiag = diagnostic.groupBy(diag => (diag.id, diag.code))
```

Where diagnostic is an ungrouped RDD of the above data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the second element of the tuple is a `CompactBuffer` and all you need is its length a `mapValues` with `_.size` should give you the required result:

```
rdd.mapValues(_.size)
```

In general you should avoid grouping just to find a `count` and use `reduceByKey` as a replacement:

```
val diagnostics: RDD[Diagnostic] = ???
diagnostics.map(d => ((d.id, d.code), 1L)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```